# Why is the standard tuning for the balalaika so weird/counterintuitive?

Tags: tuning, balalaika

I'm mainly talking about the prima balalaika, since this is the instrument whose tuning I'm familiar with.

What is the justification behind having the standard tuning for the balalaika be e-e-a? Why have two strings be tuned to the same note? What kind of music/technique is made easier to play/perform by having this kind of tuning?

To me, this is rather unintuitive as it seems like it would only serve to restrict the tonal range of the instrument, while adding little to no discernable playing benefits.

Comment: There are several different balalaikas, and most will have two strings tuned to the same note - only the contra bass has all 3 strings tuned differently, somewhat like a bass guitar. There is also a 'G triad' tuning for some. Good question!

Comment: I found a page describing the technique as "play the melody on the A string and accompany yourself on the two E strings." [This video](https://youtu.be/QQtYLF5Rjns?si=Kgm34RVFEDw6zJFA) seems to clarify that a bit, showing two techniques: At first he uses the thumb to stop both E strings, so that, along with the A string, there are only two pitches sounding. Then around 8:30 he stops the two E strings differently to create a triadic chord.

Comment: So I'm not going to post it as an answer since it's just speculation, but it seems like the three strings are not equal in role, so its "tonal range" is in fact functionally limited to the A string; they're not all "melody strings." (Plus, the assumption that a broad range is desirable might be assuming a musical goal that isn't actually present within the practice.)

Comment: You could similarly ask why there are drones on highland bagpipes. I think Andy Bonnet’s point about musical goals is well made. Flexibility may not be important in this musical context. In other words, what if restricting the tonal range is the exact playing benefit you suggest is lacking?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - at least with bagpipe drones there are two different notes playing - a 'power chord' if you like.